# How to add password parameter field without showing values via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ssm, aws-ssm

I will be taking few inputs when i'm creating the cloudformation stack. Cloudformation stack will create a SSM document (AWS systems manager) and I want to give password as an input parameter to the SSM document before the execution.

```
"parameters": {
              "sourceAMIid": {
              "type": "String",
              "description": "Source/Base AMI to be used for generating your Automated AMI",
              "default": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "HVM64"]}
                       },
               "Username": {
                           "type": "String",
                           "description": "account username/email",
                           "default": "none"
                       },
                       "password": {
                           "type": "String",
                           "description": "account password",
                           "default": "none"
                       },

                       "productName": {
                           "type": "String",
                           "description": "The syntax of this parameter is ProductName-ProductVersion.",
                           "default": {
                               "Ref": "productName"
                    }
       }
}
```

[image]

When i enter the password in this field it will show the exact word as it is. is there any way that i can define password parameter to display as below

[image]

Comment: Try using secrets manager.

Answer (score 19):

Yes you can mask your password using cloud formation template.All you need to is set "NoEcho" to "true" inside parameters as shown below.Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) and **Using Input Parameters with NoEcho for Credentials** in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) for more information.

```
"Parameters" : {
  "DBPort" : {
    "Default" : "3306",
    "Description" : "TCP/IP port for the database",
    "Type" : "Number",
    "MinValue" : "1150",
    "MaxValue" : "65535"
  },
  "DBPwd" : {
    "NoEcho" : "true",
    "Description" : "The database admin account password",
    "Type" : "String",
    "MinLength" : "1",
    "MaxLength" : "41",
    "AllowedPattern" : "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
  }
}
```

Comment: Since i'm using this under the SSM Document code,I have tried this before, it gives me error when creating the cloudformation stack

`"AutomationDoc": {
            "Type": "AWS::SSM::Document","Properties": {"DocumentType": "Automation","Content": {"schemaVersion": "0.3","parameters": {"password": {"type": "String","NoEcho":"true","description": "account password", "default": "none"},`

I'm getting this error 
_Unknown property "noEcho". (Service: AmazonSSM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDocumentContent; Request ID: 3b856651-1194-4e3f-8bc5-bf88a9b9734d)_

Comment: _Unknown property "noEcho". (Service: AmazonSSM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDocumentContent; Request ID: 3b856651-1194-4e3f-8bc5-bf88a9b9734d)_

Comment: Put `"NoEcho"` on the parameter, not on the document.

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal, this can be accomplished by using `bash` and `read -s -p`.

In the example below I have a Makefile, which reads the password, but does not echo the input to the terminal.

**The Make Command**

```
make create-test
```

**Makefile**

```
create-test: s3 delete-test
     @read -s -p "Enter DB Root Password: "  pswd; \
     aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test --template-body file://master.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=DBRootPassword,ParameterValue=$$pswd
```